# Debugging Outside Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gdb

So, literally the worst thing seems to have happened. I can't develop the iPhone app I've been working on on my MacBook as the hard drive has given in and needs to be replaced.

I'm a student at Carnegie Mellon and am now trying to use the cluster iMacs to develop the app. The issue is this - When I build and run an iPhone app from a cluster machine, I seem to require administrator privileges to use gdb. The application runs fine, but gdb doesn't work if I fail to provide these privileges.

Is there anyway for me to build the app and then run it with gdb outside of Xcode? Or is there anyway for me to get past the privilege requirement?

> Xcode version 3.2.5

I appreciate any help you guys can offer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for getting GDB running on your iDevice:
http://pod2g-ios.blogspot.in/2012/02/working-gnu-debugger-on-ios-43.html

Because the SDK location is now in the package contents of Xcode, just pull it from Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb to you desktop, and follow the tut from there.

Also, there is a thinned version already in the SDK under /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ so you can skip to 'nano entitlements.xml' in his instructions. This is what I did to get it to work for me using iOS 5.0.1 and SDK 5.1.

The only problem I am faced with when running on the iDevice is an empty .bin file when I call for a memory dump. Other than that, so far so good.

Also, if you have admin privileges, or know who does, you can change the exactable privilege to all users: "cd /usr/bin/" or wherever gdb is, "sudo -s", type password, "chmod x+a gdb" and you're good to go.